# Is there away to pass in a flow reference to a mule flow?

Tags: mule

I have a common set of steps that occur before and after an action. I would like to pass in a flow reference value to a common flow that takes these before and after actions.

is this possible in mule?

for clarity I want a flow that looks like this:

CommonStep1 --> CommonStep2 --> [InjectableFlowHere] --> CommonStep 3

I would then be able to pass this common flow a [InjectableFlowHere] component, whether it's a flowVariable or a property on the message, or something.

*net-net* I want to dependency inject a component into a flow.

**update**
I would like InjectableFlowHere to be a flowRef where the flow name is

```
<flow-ref name="#[flowVars.Prefix]GetRequestFlow" doc:name="#[flowVars.Prefix]GetRequestFlow"/>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear ....If you want to make flow-reference value dynamic and that value to be used in any part of the flow, then you can use flow variable for that

Comment: I have added an example of what I want to do

Comment: Create 'InjectableFlow' in separate flow.Add a  flowref in CommonStep1 --> CommonStep2 --> [flowRef here to call InjectableFlow] --> CommonStep 3.You can able to access `flowVars` out of any of these flow. Hope my understanding is right on your Question.If this is not, please add mule config will be helpful to answer.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense, sounds like you want me to use a choice to select a static flow based upon a flowVar. I would love to have a flow-ref that uses a flowVar.FlowName value. I'll update the question with what I would like to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set flow-ref as MEL expression, like following:

```
<flow-ref name="#[flowVars.Prefix]-flow" doc:name="flow"/>
```

For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.7.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <flow-ref name="flow-#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string']]" doc:name="flow-1"/>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="flow-1">
        <logger message="1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="flow-2">
        <logger message="2" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
</mule>
```

passing 1 or 2 as query string will route to respective sub-flow

Comment: oh! I thought it had to be a hard coded thing, since the drop down of flows is  a dropdown. thanks. I'll check this out.

Comment: Using MEL inside sub-flow works very well, I had one common flow where target flow name used to come as a http parameter and I passed it to flow-ref using MEL.

Comment: this is beautiful! thank you so much. this makes this so much easier to handle than the choice stuff I was working on. I'd upvote more than once if I could!

Comment: Nice trick but I can't use it since I have Mule CE 3.5. There is a bug which will cause NPE when using dynamic flow-ref name, see https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8973